# Django: Get notified of all changes in database

Tags: python, django, notifications

I was wandering if there's a way to get notified of any changes to objects in a Django database. Right now I just need an email if anybody adds or changes anything but it would be best if I could hook a function triggered by any change and could decide what to do.

Is there an easy way to do it in Django?

Comment: Typically end users don't change models, they just create and delete objects. So do you want to be notified of when rows are added or deleted from the database?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'objects', not 'models'. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind:

1. [Override the predefined model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) for saving.
2. Use a signal like [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save).

Here is a good article that talks about the difference between the two things listed above and when to use them:

[Django signals vs. custom save()-method](https://web.archive.org/web/20130802081636/http://www.martin-geber.com/thought/2007/10/29/django-signals-vs-custom-save-method/)

The article was written near the end of 2007, three days after the release of Django 0.96.1. However, I believe the advice the author gives still applies today.

Comment: Signals like `pre_save` and `post_save` seem to be perfect for needs, thanks.